# Android phone can send SMS messages but not receive

Tags: applications, sms

Trying to secure many of my accounts with 2FA I resorted to the SMS functionality of my phone VFD 600 phone running Android 6.0.1. I know this may not be ideal, but it is what I have.

Now, none of the messages turned up. I tried phone calls (incoming and outgoing) and sending  SMS messages, both worked just fine.

I have tried several apps (Textra, and the default ones), from all I can send messages (I tested those are received) but can't receive any message.

Changing my SIM card to a different phone, I found out that I could receive messages.

I also dial **#*#*4636*#*#** to check basic configuration, and everything seems normal.

The radio is on, LTE/GSM is on, and the SMSC is the right one for Giffgaff. Well, at least after I pressed 'refresh'.

I am absolutely clueless and rather frustrated.

Would you suggest any fix?

Comment: Are you sure you have sent an SMS using Signal? By default if the recipient is also at Signal a Signal message and not an SMS message is sent.

Comment: @Robert no, you're right, I've actually installed it but didn test signal. Did test Textra and 2 other SMS apps that come pre installed.